# Is it possible to load a custom dojo build with RequireJS?

Tags: javascript, optimization, dojo, requirejs, dgrid

Working on a project which uses RequireJS, and loads dojo / dijit / dojox / dgrid using Require rather than the Dojo loader.

I'm trying to optimize the javascript to reduce http calls, and RequireJS optimizer doesn't seem to be able to optimize the Dojo modules.

Would it be possible to create a Dojo custom build and then load it with RequireJS? I've tried a few builds and haven't been able to get it to work yet. The last Dojo build configuration I tried (which ran successfully) was:

```
var profile = {
basePath: '../src/',
action: 'release',
cssOptimize: 'comments',
mini: true,
optimize: 'closure',
layerOptimize: 'closure',

packages: [
    'dgrid',
    'dijit',
    'dojo',
    'dojox',
    'put-selector',
    'xstyle'
],

stripConsole: 'all',
selectorEngine: 'lite',

layers: {
    'dojo/dojo': {
        boot: false,
        customBase: true,
        include: [
            'dojo/_base/array',
            'dojo/_base/declare',
            'dojo/_base/fx',
            'dojo/_base/lang',
            'dojo/_base/window',
            'dojo/_base/xhr',
            'dojo/aspect',
            'dojo/cache',
            'dojo/Deferred',
            //'dojo/dojo',
            'dojo/dom-class',
            'dojo/dom-construct',
            'dojo/dom-geometry',
            'dojo/dom-style',
            'dojo/dom',
            'dojo/fx',
            'dojo/has',
            'dojo/keys',
            'dojo/mouse',
            'dojo/on',
            'dojo/promise/all',
            'dojo/query',
            'dojo/request/registry',
            'dojo/request/util',
            'dojo/sniff',
            'dojo/string',
            'dojo/store/Cache',
            'dojo/store/JsonRest',
            'dojo/store/Memory',
            'dojo/store/Observable',
            'dojo/store/util/QueryResults',
            'dojo/topic',
            'dojo/when',
            'dojox/uuid/generateRandomUuid',
            'put-selector/put',
        ]
    },
    'dijit/dijit': {
        include: [
            'dijit/_TemplatedMixin',
            'dijit/_Widget',
            'dijit/dijit',
            'dijit/form/CheckBox',
            //'dijit/form/DateTextBox', // For some reason including this module causes the Dojo build to fail?
            //'dijit/form/FilteringSelect', // For some reason including this module causes the Dojo build to fail?
            //'dijit/form/MappedTextBox', // For some reason including this module causes the Dojo build to fail?
            'dijit/form/TextBox',
            'dijit/Menu',
            'dijit/MenuItem',
            'dijit/Tooltip',
        ]
    },
    'dgrid/dgrid': {
        include: [
            'dgrid/CellSelection', // Set the cell selection model
            'dgrid/ColumnSet', //Adds frozen column capabilities.
            'dgrid/Editor',
            //'dgrid/extensions/ColumnHider', // For some reason including this module causes the Dojo build to fail?
            'dgrid/extensions/ColumnReorder',
            'dgrid/extensions/ColumnResizer',
            'dgrid/extensions/CompoundColumns',
            'dgrid/Grid',
            'dgrid/Keyboard',
            'dgrid/OnDemandGrid',
            'dgrid/Tree',
            'dgrid/util/misc',
            'dgrid/util/touch',
        ]
    },

},

staticHasFeatures: {
    'config-deferredInstrumentation': 0,
    'config-dojo-loader-catches': 0,
    'config-tlmSiblingOfDojo': 0,
    'dojo-amd-factory-scan': 0,
    'dojo-combo-api': 0,
    'dojo-config-api': 1,
    'dojo-config-require': 0,
    'dojo-debug-messages': 0,
    'dojo-dom-ready-api': 1,
    'dojo-firebug': 0,
    'dojo-guarantee-console': 1,
    'dojo-has-api': 1,
    'dojo-inject-api': 1,
    'dojo-loader': 0,
    'dojo-log-api': 0,
    'dojo-modulePaths': 0,
    'dojo-moduleUrl': 0,
    'dojo-publish-privates': 0,
    'dojo-requirejs-api': 0,
    'dojo-sniff': 1,
    'dojo-sync-loader': 0,
    'dojo-test-sniff': 0,
    'dojo-timeout-api': 0,
    'dojo-trace-api': 0,
    'dojo-undef-api': 0,
    'dojo-v1x-i18n-Api': 1,
    'dom': 1,
    'host-browser': 1,
    'extend-dojo': 1
},
```

}

However, when I try to load the optimized layer files in require, it returns this fairly cryptic error and the application doesn't load:

> Failed to load root module. Details: has.add is not a function

Also, some modules which I marked with comments above will cause the Dojo build to fail if I include them. Any ideas there?

Is it possible to make this work? Currently we're tied to using dgrid, so the only option if this doesn't work, will be to rip out RequireJS.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [source version](http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.10.4/dojo-release-1.10.4-src.zip) of the Dojo Toolkit. Built copies of AMD modules are not compatible between loaders.

Comment: Thanks for your response @mshindal. Is it possible to optimize the source version of Dojo in any way so that it can be loaded as a single file?